# Setting BorderBrush of Button with a custom template and triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to change the borderbrush property of a button in a custom template. Changing the background on mouseover using this method works just fine, but the BorderBrush? Nada.

Here's my code:

```
<Style x:Key="ImageButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Margin="1,0,0,-9">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,1,1,0" Height="94" Width="101"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Edit: Actually not even the blue borderbrush set at the beggining shows up so that may be of relevance.

Here's where the style is used if of any importance.

```
<Button Margin="191,10,138,109" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}">
    <Image/>
</Button>
```

Comment: Can you rephrase into a clear question (bring the title into the main body and word as a question)? I can't tell what you are asking. Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that, somehow the keyword search I did before the question got copied into the title. Edited for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create style setting BorderThickness to 3 but then override default visual tree so this thicknes is not taken into acount. Add this

```
 BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
```

in order to see it.

Comment: Amazing. I completely missed that. Thank you.